# Лучшие практики хранения объектов javascript на сервере

Tags: javascript, база-данных, хранение-данных

Есть приложение, написанное на AngularJs. Приложение - конструктор, пользователь может добавлять/редактировать содержимое рабочей области.

На выходе кода получается такой массив объектов

```
[{
  property1: '...',
  property2: '...',
  ...
},
{
  ...
},
...]
```

В среднем в одном объекте около 20-40 свойств, а самих объектов от 5 и более. Большинство свойств - это просто либо текстовая строка, либо массив из id-номеров. Но есть и callback-методы(функции в объекте), которые вызываются при определенных событиях.

Как лучше всего сохранить такой объект на сервере? В базе данных просто в поле text? Речь не про просто способ сохранения, способов сохранения великое множество. Хотелось бы понять как это сделать **лучше, безопаснее и оптимальней всего**.
Данные должны сохраняться при каждом действии пользователя, чтобы при обновлении страницы он не терял результат.

Comment: `text` но помните, что ограничение на него 65к символов, есть ещё `longtext`.   `На выходе кода получается такой массив объектов` - это называется JSON, это просто обязаны айтишники знать.

Comment: "Оптимальнее": думаю не гонять такие объемы на сервер при каждом действии, а хранить прямо на клиенте в каком нибудь localStorage. А на сервер сбрасывать периодически, но не очень часто, плюс по определенным событиям вроде перезагрузки страницы. А "лучше" - это зависит от того что с этими данными предстоит делать на сервере в дальнейшем помимо просто хранения. Что такое "безопаснее" не ясно.